# EWS: Get attendants' response for calendar events - "unknown", workarounds?

Tags: calendar, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I have a Java application which tries pulling down calendar events from the Exchange Web Services. Everything is working pretty fine, but `Attendee.getResponseType()` always returns "unknown".

In other threads, I've seen that this occurs because I'm pulling data from the attendee's calendar, not from the organizer. A [documentation page describing how to do this via the EWS Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633669(v=exchg.80).aspx) tells us that the first step is to

> Bind to the meeting organizer's meeting item by using its unique identifier.

How is it possible if I don't have delegation / impersonation rights for the meeting organizer? Is there any other way to get the attendants' response type?